# ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out when I try to push my code to github

Tags: github, ssh, push, connection-timeout

I got this error when I try to push my code to github.

I tried to update the config file and it is not working in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the following steps to fix this issue.

1. Generate a token in your GitHub.
2. Use the following command

   ```
   git remote set-url origin https://username:token@github.com/username/repository.git
   ```

***NOTE:*** Replace

- `username` with your GitHub username
- `token` with your generated token in step 1
- `repository` with your GitHub repository name